# How to convert tensorflow tensor to bytes?

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow

In numpy converting a np tensor to bytes can be done as follows:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]], dtype=np.uint8)
bytesArr = b.tobytes()
print(bytesArr)
```

In tensorflow you can do this to create the tensor, but how can you convert the result to a bytearray?

```
a = tf.cast(tf.constant([[1.0, 2.0], [3.0, 4.0]]), tf.uint8)

#Do conversion here
```

Also: I'm also working on a tf model wrapped in @tf.function, so eager execution is not enabled, which means I can't use the .numpy() method on the tensor.

Answer (score 1):

```
tensorByteProto = tf.io.serialize_tensor(a)
```

To extract bytes from TensorProto use `tensorByteProto.tensor_content`

Comment: second one (tf.io.serialize_tensor) works

Comment: (tf.io.serialize_tensor) seems to not be giving the same value as the numpy .tobytes() command. The bytes don't look right.

Comment: See if tf.io.serialize(a).tensor_content works

Comment: What exactly is not acceptable, becaue if you see data type using Python type(val2test) then it will show it as byte

Answer (score 0):

I had success with:

```bash
b = bytearray(tf.numpy())
```